# Simple Slider Syntax & Other Possible Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple slider, but I'm not having much luck. Here is what I'm using...

Javscript/jQuery:

```
var $item = $('.slider');
var $vpw = $('.wrapper').width();
var $start = 0;
var $end = $vpw * 3;

$('.next').click(function () {
    if ($start < $end) {
        $item.animate({
            'left': '-=$vpm'
        });
    }
});
$('.prev').click(function () {
    if ($end < $start) {
        $item.animate({
            'left': '+=$vpm'
        });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="item-post" style="background: url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-LjJWOy7K-Q0/VOUJbMJr0_I/AAAAAAAAdAg/I2V70xea8YE/s320-c/enviroment-5.jpg) center"></div>
        <div class="item-post" style="background: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-l3UnbspFvv0/VOUK8M-34UI/AAAAAAAAdA0/ooGyXrHdNcg/s320-c/enviroment-2.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="item-post" style="background: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-cun1kQ42IBs/VOUaSPfnebI/AAAAAAAAdBQ/yTEj9K-BGdk/s320-c/fashion-3.jpg)"></div>
        <div class="prev"></div>
        <div class="next"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.item-post {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-position: center !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.item-post:first-of-type { left: 0; }
.item-post:nth-of-type(2) { left: 100%; }
.item-post:last-of-type { left: 200%; }
.prev, .next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 25px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.prev {
    left: 0;
}
.next {
    right: 0;
}
```

JSHint tells me there is a syntax error, must likely because I'm not using `.width()` correctly, but I'm unsure how to. What I'm trying to do is grab the width of that element.

The `$end` variable is set to `$vpm*3` only because that's how many `.item-post` at 100% elements there are, and I'm not sure if this is the best way. I can't just count the number of `.item-post` because this example has been dumbed down. The original markup is metro-like, and contains 5 `.item-post` elements within the width of `.slider`. That means 15 item-post elements in about 300% of the `.slider` element.

My goal is to create a slider that scrolls right/left when clicking `.next/.prev`, but not outside existing content, and at increments equal to the width of the parent(`.slider`).

I'm not even sure if my logic is sound in the creation of this script.

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/51maaks8/5/

Comment: I beleav you should not use: var $var = something. only $var = something. And remember $end $start in if statements.

Comment: I followed your suggestions, but the script still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your JavaScript to either this (semi-colons added):

```
var $item = $('.slider');
var $vpw = $('.wrapper').width();
var $start = 0;
var $end = $vpw * 3;
```

Or this (`var`'s removed):

```
var $item = $('.slider'),
$vpw = $('.wrapper').width(),
$start = 0,
$end = $vpw * 3;
```

To fix the syntax issue.